# Length of angle bisector in terms of sides.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

If the bisector of $\angle A$ in triangle $ABC$ meets $BC$ at $U$, prove that $AU^2=bc(1-a^2/(b+c)^2)$. (Where a, b, c are sides opposite to $A, B, C$ respectively).

I am not able to do anything. A hint to solve this in pre college level will be appreciated.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Ok. I will try making the title better

Comment: If I remember correctly, we can use the sine theorem (and trigonometric identities of double angles) to prove this.

Comment: Thanks but i got the answer my dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use angle bisector theorem, BU = kc and CU = kb for some non-zero constant k.
2. Apply consine law to $\triangle BAU$ and $\triangle CAU$.
3. Try to eliminate the term involving $ \cos \dfrac {A}{2}$.
4. Note that $k = ... = \dfrac {a}{b + c}$.

---

From (2.) $(kb)^2 = AU^2 + b^2 - 2AUb \cos  \dfrac {A}{2}$

Multiply throughout by c to get $c(kb)^2 = cAU^2 + cb^2 - 2AUbc \cos  \dfrac {A}{2}$.

Do the similar trick to the other equation to get $b(kc)^2 = bAU^2 + bc^2 - 2AUbc \cos  \dfrac {A}{2}$.

Do (3.) by subtraction.

Comment: I tried that but I am not getting the answer I also tried linking it with sine and cosine rules but still I am stuck with a long weird equation. Can you please post your answer.

Comment: @AryanRaina I have added more detail. Hope you can go on.

Comment: Thanks I did it. Now I am feeling good. Take my upvote my dude.

Comment: @AryanRaina Glad to hear that.